# Use hyphen ("-") in SQLite LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to use a hyphen in a SQLite LIKE string, but it is not working.

Sample search string:

```
SELECT Name from Table where Name LIKE 'abc - %'
```

This returns zero results.  Whereas the following will, of course, return all names that start with 'abc'.

```
SELECT Name from Table where Name LIKE 'abc%'
```

I've tried using the ESCAPE clause like this:

```
SELECT Name from Table where Name LIKE 'abc !-' ESCAPE '!'
```

But again, no Names are returned.

Oddly, all of the other questions seem to refer to escaping the '%' and '_' characters, but none address the escaping of the '-' (hyphen).

How can I do this?

Comment: A hyphen should not require escaping. Copy a hyphen from the table and paste it into http://unicodelookup.com and make sure its a basic ansi character (0x2d -) as opposed to say a Unicode hyphen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the referenced website returns 2918 results (if no subset is chosen) or nothing if latin is chosen.  The same results occur when typing a hyphen from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it appears that the lack of results when a hyphen is present is a bug in SQLiteStudio (using V3.1.0) the GUI I'm using with SQLite.   When I tried the SQL statement (with the '-' and without the ESCAPE clause) in the Command Line Interface, it returned the expected results.